# ffmpeg concat avi files loosing the audio

Tags: ffmpeg

Hey i have 2 AVI files that i want to concatenate them to one output.

the files path is written in text file (mylist.txt):

file1.avi - contain video only.
file2.avi - contain video and audio.

**i execute the next command:**

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\ffmpeg\mylist.txt -c copy C:\ffmpeg\output.avi
```

mylist.txt=

file 'C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\file1.avi'

file 'C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\file2.avi'

the output file is concatenate of the 2 files. but the sound from file2.avi is not there.

so how can i contact them without delete the sound???

console log:

```
C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\mylist.txt -
c copy C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\output.avi
ffmpeg version N-78949-g6f5048f Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenc
ore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --ena
ble-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable
-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --ena
ble-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx
264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable
-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 27.101 / 57. 27.101
  libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.100 /  6. 39.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, concat, from 'C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 523 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 720
x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 523 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 30k tbc
File 'C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\output.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\output.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf57.28.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 D
AR 16:9], q=2-31, 523 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[concat @ 0000000000452620] New audio stream 0:1 at pos:10038 and DTS:100.104s
frame= 6000 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   13020kB time=00:03:20.23 bitrate= 532.7kbits
/s speed=1.39e+003x
video:12870kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
 overhead: 1.159987%
```

thanks.

Comment: You need to show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i file1.avi -i file2.avi`

Comment: hey i added the console log

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful, but I am specifically looking for the info about your inputs. See the command in my previous comment.

Comment: what info about the inputs???
mylist.txt: 
file 'C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\file1.avi'
file 'C:\motionbee\ffmpeg\bin\file2.avi'

Comment: I need to see the contents of each individual input file that you are attempting to concatenate.